# Iterative method proof

Tags: numerical-methods

We choose the iterative method $$\vec{u}^{i+1} = Q\vec{u}^i + \vec{s}$$ with $\vec{u}^0 = 0$ to solve $A\vec{u} = \vec{f}$.

I want to proof that for $\vec{u}^i$ the following holds:
$$
\vec{u}^i = (I - Q^i)A^{-1}\vec{f}
$$
Under certain assumptions. Also, we can then determine $\vec{s}$.

I have tried to validate this equation, but to no luck. I think I'm missing an obvious identity.

Comment: Your question does not make sense as long as you don't define $Q$ nor $Q^i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal I believe that you first have to assume that the iterative method is consistent, i.e. that the true solution $\vec{u}$ is a fixed point of the iteration:
$$
\vec{u} = Q \vec{u} + \vec{s},
$$
or equivalently
$$
\vec{s} = (I - Q) \vec{u} = (I - Q) A^{-1} \vec{f},
$$
which provides an expression for $\vec{s}$ as requested.

Now, given $\vec{u}^0 = 0$ it follows that
\begin{align*}
\vec{u}^1 &= \vec{s}, \\
\vec{u}^2 &= (I + Q) \vec{s}, \\
\vec{u}^3 &= (I + Q + Q^2) \vec{s}, \\
\vdots \\
\vec{u}^i &= \left ( \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} Q^j \right) \vec{s}. \\
\end{align*}
At this point it will be necessary to assume that $Q$ satisfies $\rho(Q) < 1$, where $\rho(Q)$ denotes the spectral radius of $Q$. If so, then the above sum can be expressed as $(I-Q^i)(I-Q)^{-1}$ and we have
$$
\vec{u}^i = (I-Q^i)(I-Q)^{-1} \vec{s} = (I-Q^i) A^{-1} \vec{f}
$$
as desired.

Note that the two assumptions (consistency and spectral radius smaller than one) are necessary and sufficient conditions for the method to be convergent.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize it has to be consistent